# Problem with CSS selector

Tags: css

I have a link `<a href="..." class="fancylink">text</a>`

I used the code

```
.fancy
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

but it still underlined, if I set it to "underlined" it double underline it.

So I can't take control of a link style using a Class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you are having border bottom there, try this:

```
.fancy
{
  text-decoration:none;
  border:none;
}
```

Now apply that class to your link:

```
<a href="whatever" class="fancy">Link</a>
```

**Edit:**

Since you have updated your question. You have defined style `fancy` but you are applying class `fancylink` to link which is wrong, use the same class name in the link too, that is `fancy`.

Answer (score 2):

If it gets "double underline", it means you have a bottom border.
Use a tool like FireBug to figure out the style exactly, it is also possible you'd have a stronger selector hiding the new rule.

Answer (score 0):

I can almost bet that the issue is "the cascade".  I recommend using Firebug to debug your css.

http://getfirebug.com/

Also, if you have IE8 installed the developer tools are good too.

Comment: i use stylizer, it's better, but didn't thought of the bottom border :P

Answer (score 0):

You link sets a class of `fancylink` and your css defines a class call `fancy`.

Make them both the same and you'll be in business.